# How can I make my nav bar resize dynamically on smaller windows?

Tags: html, css, navbar

Ok, so I built my nav bar and it looks exactly how I want it, but throws my css right out the window if I make the window any smaller than 75% of my screen. How can I code this more efficiently so the nav bar is maintained at smaller sizes? Any help is appreciated, I'm very new at this.

css:

```css
div#hmenu { 
   margin: 0; 
   padding: .3em 0 .3em 0; 
   /*background: #ddeebb; */
   width: 100%; 
   text-align: center; 
} 

div#hmenu ul { 
   list-style: none; 
   margin: 0; 
   padding: 0; 
} 

div#hmenu ul li { 
   margin: 0; 
   padding: 0; 
   display: inline; 
} 

div#hmenu ul a:link{ 
   margin: 0; 
   padding: .3em 1em .3em 1em; 
   text-decoration: none; 
   font-size: medium; 
   color: #ffffff; 
} 

 div#hmenu ul a:visited{ 
   margin: 0; 
   padding: .3em 1em .3em 1em; 
   text-decoration: none; 
   font-weight: bold; 
   font-size: medium; 
   color: #ffffff; 
} 



div#hmenu ul a:hover{ 
   margin: 0; 
   padding: .3em 1em .3em 1em; 
   text-decoration: none;  
   font-size: medium; 
   color: #000000; 
   background-color: #FFFFFF; 
}
```

HTML below:

```html
<!--- my nav bar -->
<div id="hmenu">
<ul>
<li><a href="#home_new.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#home_copy_mp2.php">Explore our Collection</a></li>
<li><a href="#about_our_site.php">About the archive</a></li>
<li><a href="#our_staff.php">Our Staff</a></li>
<li><a href="#donate.php">Donate</a></li>
<li><a href="#exhibitions.php">Exhibitions</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact.php">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You'll most likely have to use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) to achieve this.

Comment: I was totally reading about this today, thanks! so, say, @media (min-width: 700px) ?

Comment: Does  `div#hmenu { /*other stuff*/min-width: 50em; }` give you the result you expect? Or `div#hmenu ul a:link { /* other stuff */  font-size: 1.98vw; }`

Comment: yes it does, works ok.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it!
I had forgotten I had actually thrown in an `@media` later on in the css (was playing with the jumbotron) and forgot to fully comment it out. Your comment made me check and see my mistake. So media queries can both solve AND create problems...

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1370px) {
    body.hero-image #main > .hero-container .img-wide {
        display: inline;
    }
}
```